# How to recover questions from my old, post-banned account?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

My previous account was blocked for no big reason, all my questions were genuine and appreciated. Is there any way so that I unblocked that account or I import my questions to my new account?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to point out your previous account?

Comment: user1949991 , hope you will allow asking questions from that account

Comment: We can't do anything about question-asking bans, as those are imposed at the system level. Looking at your previous account, you were just on the verge of being banned. Take the time to go back through your previous questions and improve them, following the above-linked guides. Do not create new accounts to work around this ban.

Comment: okk..can i get some point of being faithful to tell ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### NO.

Don't create a new account if you are banned! That ruins the whole point of the ban. Instead, improve your old downvoted/deleted questions and the ban will be automatically removed.

That's **exactly what it says** at the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) that the ban page gives you. I suggest you read it.

Comment: actually i wanted to use it for professional front. can you do something on my account and see if its possible ?

Comment: @user2205104 The only way to be unbanned is to improve your old questions. Again, did you even read the link that you were sent to?

Comment: Worse, if you create a new account, you probably end with an IP ban.

Comment: @user2205104 Do you not understand what a ban is? It's there to discourage behavior.. copying content would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Have you deleted some of your questions?  If so, undelete them and try to imporve on them.

Comment: okk..thank you....will do so.